# Using RNG in comparison only returns the Else variable

Tags: javascript, html

So trying to make a Higher or lower game (1st javascript project)

I run into a snag when I try and use a random generated number in the comparison.

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <p id="rngout"></p>
 <input type="number" id="a">
 <input type="number" id="b">
 <p id="comparison"></p>


 <button id="submit">Compare</button>

 <script>

 window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById("rngout").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1 );;
 }

 document.getElementById('submit').onclick = compare;

 function compare() {

 var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
 a = parseFloat(a);

 var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
 b = parseFloat(b);

 var comparison;

 if(a > b) {
 comparison = '>';
 } else if(a < b) {
 comparison = '<';
 } else {
 comparison = '=';
 }

 document.getElementById('comparison').innerHTML = comparison;

 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

What I want is to use the output of the window.onload function - what goes into id="rngout" to be used in the comparison below. If I use 2 user inputs (currently how it is) then it works.

Be gentle, its my first time!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to use the randomly generated number to do the comparison with one input. For that, you need to store the generated number in a variable and then use the variable in comparison. In following example, I save the random no in the variable randomNo and then I am using input a and randomNo in comparison. Let me know if this is not what you expect.

```js
 var randomNo = 0;
 window.onload = function() {
 randomNo = document.getElementById("rngout").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1 );;
 }

 document.getElementById('submit').onclick = compare;

 function compare() {

 var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
 a = parseFloat(a);

 var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
 b = parseFloat(b);

 var comparison;

 if(a > randomNo) {
 comparison = '>';
 } else if(a < randomNo) {
 comparison = '<';
 } else {
 comparison = '=';
 }

 document.getElementById('comparison').innerHTML = comparison;

 }
```

```html
 <p id="rngout"></p>
 <input type="number" id="a">
 <input type="number" id="b">
 <p id="comparison"></p>


 <button id="submit">Compare</button>
```